# Laravel CSS file link correction

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

I need to move a laravel setup to another server.
Before moving I am testing the same on my localhost.
Everything appears to work right except I am getting wrong link for CSS, js files like 
`GET 
http://127.0.0.1/css/main.css`

whereas my laravel phyiscal folders are like this
`e:\wamp\www\test\server-migrate\megashopping_dk\css\main.css`

Now I don't know where to define the path in laravel for CSS, Js.

Comment: All of your javascript and css files should be in the public folder. The recommended setup has the DocumentRoot pointed to your project's `public` folder, so all files are served out of there.

Comment: to solve this quickly: (extending @aynber 's answer) You can use a symbolic link to that location

Answer (score 0):

if you have a layouts.blade.php file which you use on every page of your website, you should define the path there with this code

`{{ URL::to('/') }}/css/main.css`

this code goes to the homepage of your website and then goes to css/main.css

Let me know if it worked

Comment: I have two folders in the root like `megashopping_dk` and `megashopping_dk_files`. the 1st folder contains folders like `backend, compaing, css, js ...` and the second folder contains `app, bootstrap, config, database, public, resources, storage...` and the index.php file in the first folder have these lines `require __DIR__.'/../megashopping_dk_files/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

Comment: @Pawan your public root folder is /public you should move your css and js to a folder under /public

Comment: @Thomas I have already copied that. but the result is still the same.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken the second folder is the laravel folder so you should place everything for your site there

Comment: @gator29 - like which folder in the first folder will go in the second folder(laravel folder). the first folder contains - `backend, compaign, css, fonts, js, lib,newdesign, test, uploads, index.php` and I am accssing the first folder index.php. Now just to give example I am getting the image link like - `http://127.0.0.1/img/logo-white.png` whereas the physicalpath for it is `e:\wamp\www\test\server-migrate\megashopping_dk\logo-white.png`

Comment: Laravel has already an index.php inside the public folder which loads everything you need for laravel, so you don't need a second folder outside the laravel project. So just place every folder you make and you need to access everywhere on your site in the public folder of the laravel project

Comment: The folder I have in hand. There is no `index.php` in the laravel folder.

Comment: It probably is in the public folder in the laravel folder

Comment: it is not there as well. however just while testing - I copied the folders `css, img, uploads` to `e:\wamp\www`. The site is showing perfectly now. So I think somewhere some path is defined for the these folders, which is searching these folders in the root. Just can't make out where it is defined.

Comment: Do you have any experience with laravel?

Comment: No, I have a good experience in Yii2. I am dealing with Laravel for the first time.

Comment: I recommend you to read the documentation on laravel's website, it's documentation is really well made

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your assets (js & css) somewhere under `/public`

You can include it like this:

```
<script src="{{ secure_asset('bower\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ secure_asset('bower\materialize\dist\js\materialize.min.js') }}"></script>
```

The file in this example is located at project path

> /public/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

Comment: In which file I need to add the code `<script src="{{ secure_asset('bower\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js') }}"></script>` as also I need to add the `img` and `css`

Comment: A blade where you need them